# Oriented Object PHP autoloader issue

Tags: php, oop, autoloader

I encounterd a little problem with my classes : they simply do not load through my autoloader.

I get this message error :

> Warning:
>   require(C:\wamp64\www\blog\appAutoloader.php/Table/PostsTable.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\blog\app\Autoloader.php on line 23
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\wamp64\www\blog\appAutoloader.php/Table/PostsTable.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\wamp64\www\blog\app\Autoloader.php on line 23

---

**Factory class** :

```
use Core\config;
use Core\Database\MysqlDatabase;

class App {

public $title = "My super site";
private $db_instance;
private static $_instance;

public static function getInstance()
{
    if (is_null(self::$_instance))
    {
        self::$_instance = new App();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public static function load()
{
    session_start();

    require ROOT . '/app/Autoloader.php';
    App\Autoloader::register();

    require ROOT .'/core/Autoloader.php';
    Core\Autoloader::register();
}

public function getTable($name)
{
    $class_name = '\\App\\Table\\' . ucfirst($name) .'Table';
    return new $class_name($this->getDb());
}

public function getDb()
{
    $config = Config::getInstance(ROOT . '/config/config.php');
    if (is_null($this->db_instance)) {
        $this->db_instance = new MysqlDatabase($config->get('db_name'), $config->get('db_user'), $config->get('db_pass'), $config->get('db_host'));
    }

    return $this->db_instance;
}
}
```

**Namespace App autoloader class** :

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Autoloader {

static function register()
{
    spl_autoload_register(array(__CLASS__, 'autoload')); // __CLASS__ load the current class
}

static function autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, __NAMESPACE__ .'\\') === 0) {
        $class = str_replace(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\', '', $class); // _NAMESPACE_ load the current name_space
        $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
        require __DIR__ . 'Autoloader.php/' . $class . '.php'; // __DIR__ = the parent folder. Here "app"
    }

}
}
```

**Namespace Core autoloader class** :

```
<?php

namespace Core;

class Autoloader {

static function register()
{
    spl_autoload_register(array(__CLASS__, 'autoload')); // __CLASS__ load the current class
}

static function autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, __NAMESPACE__ .'\\') === 0) {
        $class = str_replace(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\', '', $class); // _NAMESPACE_ load the current name_space
        $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
        require __DIR__ . 'Autoloader.php/' . $class . '.php'; // __DIR__ = the parent folder. Here "app"
    }

}
}
```

**Empty PostTable**

```
namespace App\Table;

use Core\Table\Table;

class PostsTable extends Table
{

}
```

**Index page** :

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));
require ROOT . '/app/App.php';
App::load();
$app = App::getInstance();

$posts = $app->getTable('Posts');
var_dump($posts->all());
```

How to make it works please?

Comment: Why don't you use composer?

Comment: I agree with @Arslan.H - there's no reason not to use composer, as you can completely forget about autoloading problems forever. If you decide to go down your own route, I will wish you the best of luck sorting this out. Just remember - there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I disagree, if you want to know how a wheel works truly, then create one yourself, there is nothing wrong with re-inventing anything.

Comment: if you want to see a really good implantation of an autoloader, you can check mine out in my framework I am building  https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/blob/master/EVO/Autoloader.php, yours is far to simplistic and why 2 no need for 2 surly.

Comment: here is the UnitTest class for it as well  https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/blob/master/PHPUnit/test/EVO/AutoloaderTest.php , You can register namespace path pairs, which is Awesome....

Comment: PS. your issue is casing most likly,  this `require ROOT . '/app/App.php';`  is a hint.  If your file is `app/table/PostsTable`  That's not `App\Table\PostTable`

Comment: See this `C:\wamp64\www\blog\appAutoloader.php/Table/PostsTable.php` is not `C:\wamp64\www\blog\App\Table/PostsTable.php`  Cha Cha `appAutoloader.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS I said in the comments check this path

```
require(C:\wamp64\www\blog\appAutoloader.php/Table/PostsTable.php)
```

Doesn't look right to me

```
require(C:\wamp64\www\blog\ [appAutoloader.php] /Table/PostsTable.php)
```

What's that bit doing there....

Also namespace of `App` is not `app` for the folder its `App` because this may work on Windows but you will find it does not work on Linux.  Because Linux paths are case sensitive, and windows are not.

Further this makes little to no sense

```
 require __DIR__ . 'Autoloader.php/' . $class . '.php'; // __DIR__ = the parent folder. Here "app"
```

Require 2 files?  Paths don't work that way, not that I am aware of at least.

On top of that your implementation ignores the `_`  Typically underlines will be part of the class name but are replaced by directory, this allows a shorter namespace.  So for example instead of having a namespace like this

```
     Namespace \APP\Table;
     class PostsTable  ..
```

You could have a class in the same place Like so

```
     Namespace \APP;
     class Table_PostsTable  ..
```

With a shorter namespace but still located in the `App/Table/PostsTable.php` file.  However, that's just how I read the spec for PSR autoloaders.

**PRO TIP**

Take this path `C:\wamp64\www\blog\appAutoloader.php/Table/PostsTable.php` open the file browser on you desktop and see if it pulls up the file by pasting it into the navigation bar.  It wont, but you can be sure your path is wrong by eliminating the code.

Comment: Thank you I followed what you said, and managed to fix my problem :)

Thanks others as well for your support !

Comment: See I know these things because I have re-invented the wheel for fun and profit several times.  Nothing wrong with learning how these things work...  In fact learn PHP, and all the frameworks fall to your feet.